# Documentation on archiveArtifacts command in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a basic Jenkins pipeline. The build and testing are successful but I'm looking at how to archive the build. For context, this is a simple Rust webserver.

Under the [pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) documentation in the Basic Steps plugin, it has the `archive` function. But it says:

> Archives build output artifacts for later use. As of Jenkins 2.x, you may use the more configurable `archiveArtifacts`.

I cannot find any documentation on `archiveArtifacts`. There are some examples, but I would like to look at the documentation for it, what parameters it accepts, i.e. what makes it more configurable than `archive`.

My question: is there a place where this documentation is best found? [jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io) is incomplete and [wiki.jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/) is missing this command.

Comment: I can't close it, but I found what I needed. The documentation is built into Jenkins _Pipeline Syntax_ of your job.

Comment: The snippet generator (what you found) is generally the easiest and maps closest to what version of everything you are actually running. The documentation is generally poor and I always have to go directly to the source code.

Comment: @pmbotter - In case the job is written in Jenkinsfile, I found these two short tutorials very useful (just to get started):
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/   https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Reporting-test-results-and-storing-artifacts

Answer (score 47):

I suggest [archiveArtifacts: Archive the artifacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#code-archiveartifacts-code-archive-the-artifacts) from the [Pipeline Steps Reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/).

> Archives the build artifacts (for example, distribution zip files or
>   jar files) so that they can be downloaded later. Archived files will
>   be accessible from the Jenkins webpage.  Normally, Jenkins keeps
>   artifacts for a build as long as a build log itself is kept, but if
>   you don't need old artifacts and would rather save disk space, you can
>   do so.
>
> Note that the Maven job type automatically archives any produced Maven
>   artifacts. Any artifacts configured here will be archived on top of
>   that. Automatic artifact archiving can be disabled under the advanced
>   Maven options.

- `artifacts`
  You can use wildcards like 'module/dist/**/*.zip'. See the includes attribute of Ant fileset for the exact format. The base directory is the workspace. You can only archive files that are located in your workspace.

  - Type: `String`
- `allowEmptyArchive` (optional)
  Normally, a build fails if archiving returns zero artifacts. This option allows the archiving process to return nothing without failing the build. Instead, the build will simply throw a warning.

  - Type: `boolean`
- `excludes` (optional)
  Optionally specify the 'excludes' pattern, such as "foo/bar/**/*". A file that matches this mask will not be archived even if it matches the mask specified in 'files to archive' section.

  - Type: `String`

Comment: The part that you where mentioned that "You can only archive files that are located in your workspace." saved me.

Comment: Knowing what parameters exist is great, but an example of the syntax might also help: `archiveArtifacts artifacts: './core', allowEmptyArchive: 'true'`

Comment: I don't understand the part "You can only archive files that are located in your workspace."?? Am I not always in my workspace? Is there more than one workspace?

Comment: The `Jenkinsfile` is totally free to create files outside of the workspace and those are files you cannot archive with `archiveArtifacts`.

Comment: You can always use a script to copy files into the workspace, and archive from there

Comment: I just want to add:

I couldn't find documentation on the last option 'onlyIfSuccessful' in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/.

But the Snippet Generator (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) helped me out: opening the Pipeline Syntax page on Jenkins allowed me to build an example snippet for a pipeline in just a few clicks.
It explained this option as "Archive artifacts only if build is successful".

Comment: Must the file(s) being archived exist when the call to archiveArtifacts is done, or is it declarative such that they will be archived at the end of the job?