# Adding Jenkins archiveArtifacts for multiple files but not on a single line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I've seen the answers to [Jenkins: archiveArtifacts - multiple distinct files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866752/jenkins-archiveartifacts-multiple-distinct-files) and [Jenkins multiple artifacts for the same build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823684/jenkins-multiple-artifacts-for-the-same-build) and I've looked at the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#code-archiveartifacts-code-archive-the-artifacts) (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022804/264822) but none of them explain how you can split a long line of files over multiple lines (to improve readability?)

A short example would be:

```
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper-dump.json, build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper.log'
```

If I try to split this line the parsing of Jenkinsfile fails. Splitting with single quotes:

```
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper-dump.json,'
        'build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper.log'
```

gives me:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 116: unexpected token
```

while splitting without quotes:

```
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper-dump.json,
        build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper.log'
```

gives me:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 112: expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 112, column 75.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\` worked:

```
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper-dump.json, \
        build_wrapper_output_directory/build-wrapper.log'
```